# Длинные имена в имени сервера

Tags: сервер, ip

День добрый, в компании имя сервера задал типа `MYPR-SERVGD`, иногда возникали проблемы с доступом к расшареным папкам (сетевой имя компа не найдено), сейчас сменил имя на 4 буквы без каких либо - _ ( и прочих знаков, 1 день полёт - нормальный, правильно я понимаю, что проблема была именно в длинном имени компа и это (-) знаке?

Так же заметил что если к папке обращаться не через имя `\\MYPR-SERVGD\Shared folder а через IP \\192.***.**.* \Shared folder`, то ресурс становится доступен быстрее, но при копировании появляется сообщение

> Копирование этого файла может на нести вред вашему компьютеру (OS Win7)

Можно как-то отключить это уведомление или добавить IP сервера в доверенную зону? Если да, то как?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Блин, вот и название вопроса я написал )))) масло масленое! А надо-то было "Количество символом в имени компьютера"!!

Comment: так исправьте, это возможно для своего вопрса

Answer (score 1):

Длина и имя в пределах разумного. Символ разрешен, количество символов - 15 максимально. Единственное предположение - по какой-то причине не было ответа от сервера, можно было бы глянуть сетевую активность снифером и попытаться найти проблему.

Когда вы пользуетесь IP компьютеру нет необходимости широковещательно определять клиента (кстатит тот самый IP), а значит и задержка минимальная, обусловлена только задержкой работы самого протокола.

Что касается списка доверенных узлов, где-то была такая опция, но не вспомнить. Поэтому можно всю сеть сделать довереной, в настройках это есть. Кроме того, может, где-то в недрах тех же настроек найдете доверенные узлы.

Обычно чтобы ускорить поиск имен в сети Windows используется wins сервер.

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде начинаю понемногу понимать!

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте тип сети. Может у Вас общественная стоит. В зависимости от типа сети меняются настройки брэндмауера. Доверенная зона: свойства обозревателя-безопасность-надежные узлы. Добавьте необходимый узел и поиграйтесь с настройками